# Photo does not display in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I spent a few hours trying to display the image in Django, I am trying to display a wordcloud in Django.

Here's my views.py:

```
import tweepy
from tweepy.auth import OAuthHandler
from .models import Tweet
from .models import Dates
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, InvalidPage
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db import models, transaction
from django.db.models import Q
import os
import tweepy as tw
import pandas as pd
import nltk
from .forms import TweetIDForm
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from django import template
import urllib, base64
import io

import requests

consumer_key = 'consumer_key'
consumer_secret = 'consumer_secret'
access_token = 'access_token'
access_token_secret = 'access_token_secret'

def clean_tweet_id(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = TweetIDForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            tweet_id = form.cleaned_data.get("tweet_id")
            auth = tw.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
            auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
            api = tw.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
            
            twtjson = requests.get('https://publish.twitter.com/oembed?url=' + tweet_id + '&omit_script=true')
            tweets = twtjson.json()
            tweet = tweets.get('html')   

            ida = tweet_id.split('/')[-1].split('?')[0]
 
            identification = int(ida)
            status = api.get_status(identification)

            user_name = status.user.screen_name
            words = ""
            for twt in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q='to:'+user_name, result_type='recent', timeout=999999).items(100):
                if hasattr(twt, 'in_reply_to_status_id_str'):
                    if twt.in_reply_to_status_id_str==ida:
                        tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(twt.text)
                        txt = nltk.Text(tokens)
                        fd_words = nltk.FreqDist(txt)
                        mostcommonwordsoftxt = fd_words.most_common(100)
                        wordc = str(mostcommonwordsoftxt)
                        print(wordc)
                        wc = WordCloud(width = 800, height = 400, background_color ='white', stopwords = STOPWORDS, max_font_size = 12)
                        wcloud = wc.generate(wordc)
                        cloudtofile = wcloud.to_file('Wordcloud.png')        
            return render(request, 'tweet/tweet-list.html', {'form': form, 'tweet_id':tweet_id, 'tweets': tweet,'image':cloudtofile})
 
    else:
        form = TweetIDForm()
        return render(request, 'tweet/tweet-list.html', {'form': form})
        
def home(request):
    context = {}
    context['word'] = clean_tweet_id(request)
    return render(request, 'tweet/dashboard.html', context)
```

My HTML template:

```
<html lang="en"> 
<h1>Tweets</h1>

<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<body> 
    {% if tweets %}
    {{tweets|safe}}<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    {% load static %}
     <img src=  "{% static 'Wordcloud.png' %}" />
    {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to display the wordcloud that is generated through Django. However, for some reason, the image does not display, despite the fact that the image does get generated, its just the user cannot see the image in the webserver.

Comment: The web server under which the `Django` code runs does not have direct access to your filesystem. Therefore, `/Users/{name}/Downloads/twitter/Wordcloud.png` is not a valid URL within the app. `cloudtofile = wcloud.to_file('Wordcloud.png')` should be changed to save the world cloud file in your `static` folder and change the `src` attribute of the `img` tag to point to the file in the `static` folder.

Comment: Okay thanks for letting me know.

Comment: I fixed it and the code is `cloudtofile = wcloud.to_file('Wordcloud.png')` in `views.py` and `<img src=  "{% static 'Wordcloud.png' %}" />` in the HTML template. However, after I fixed it, the image still does not display.

Comment: Update your question with the changes you made. We can't tell where you're saving the word cloud file now. Either way, your problem now is that you're not saving the word cloud file in the right place.

Comment: You're still not saving the word cloud file in your `static` folder. You should use something like `cloudtofile = wcloud.to_file(os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'Wordcloud.png'))`. I am using that `STATIC_ROOT` is set in your `settings.py` module.